# Update is not working Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

update button is not functioning properly it is just adding up new row with data instead of updating

```
Dim currentrow As Long

        Private Sub cmdFindNext_Click()
        Dim lastrow
        Dim evtname As String
        lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        evtname = TB1.Text
        For currentrow = 4 To lastrow
        If Cells(currentrow, 1).Text = evtname Then
        TB1.Text = Cells(currentrow, 1).Text
        ComboB.Text = Cells(currentrow, 4)
        startdate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 2)
        enddate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 3)
        End If
        Next currentrow
        TB1.SetFocus
        End Sub

        Private Sub cmdFindPrevious_Click()
        Dim lastrow
        Dim evtname As String
        lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        evtname = TB1.Text
        For currentrow = lastrow To 4 Step -1
        If Cells(currentrow, 1).Text = evtname Then
        TB1.Text = Cells(currentrow, 1).Text
        ComboB.Text = Cells(currentrow, 4)
        startdate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 2)
        enddate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 3)
        End If
        Next currentrow
        TB1.SetFocus
        End Sub

        Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
        Cells(currentrow - 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(TB1.Text,     startdate.Text, enddate.Text, ComboB.Text)

        End Sub
```

[image: update]

What can i do about that update i added textboxes to make it simple that date controls but still its same

Comment: have you tried changing `currentrow` to `currentrow - 1` ?

Comment: @MacroMan you are right it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead - there is no need to assign variables for the scope of this sub and you can do the whole thing with a single line of code:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
    Cells(currentrow - 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(TB1.Text, startdate.Text, enddate.Text, ComboB.Text)
End Sub
```

---

To get the right row rather than the last row:

You need to exit your loop when the condition has been found, so that `currentrow` retains the correct value. In both of your find subs, exit the loop at the end of your `If` block:

```
'// existing code here
Exit For '<~~ add this in both subs.
End If
```

Once you have done that, change `currentrow - 1` back to `currentrow` to make sure it's the right row.

Comment: it is helpful but it is only updating the LAST ROW how can i set it up to look for data and update in any row

Comment: we don't know where `currentrow` gets it's value from, so there is not enough information for us to help

Comment: sorry for that in edit it was removed "Dim currentrow As Long"

Comment: that just tells me how it was declared, we need to know where it gets it's value from.

Comment: i just update the code in question that is full code for FIND and Update button i really don't know currentrow gets value from!

Comment: is it possible to update two sheets at a time with same data in same rows same column sheet 1 and sheet 2

Comment: Yes, but that's outside the scope of this question - please start a new question for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103115/discussion-between-muhammad-khurrum-butt-and-macro-man).

Answer (score 1):

Try this sub

```
  Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
   Dim evtname As String, sname As String, sdate As String, edate As String
    evtname = TB1.Text
      Cells(currentrow - 1, 1).Value = evtname
    sname = ComboB.Text
     Cells(currentrow - 1, 4).Value = sname
   sdate = startdate.Text
       Cells(currentrow - 1, 2).Value = sdate
   edate = enddate.Text
  Cells(currentrow - 1, 3).Value = edate
End Sub
```